# Getting referenced tables in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I have a list of foreign keys. I'd like to find out the tables where these FK's point to and the actual key the point to.

I've got a list of FK's like so:

```
columnName0, columnName1, columnName2
```

Foreign key references

- `columnName0` references `table0.idTable0`
- `columnName1` references `table1.idTable1`
- `columnName2` references `table2.idTable2`

Some sample tables:

**Table0**:

```
idTable0, PK
name
```

**Table1**:

```
idTable1, PK
age
```

**Table2**:

```
idTable2, PK
createdOn
```

A sample result:

```
| column      | referenced_column | referenced_table |
|-------------|-------------------|------------------|
| columnName0 | idTable0          | table0           |
| columnName1 | idTable1          | table1           |
| columnName2 | idTable2          | table2           |
```

I'm trying to translate something I do in MySQL like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    COLUMN_NAME AS column,
    REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME AS referenced_column,
    REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME AS referenced_table
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE 
    COLUMN_NAME IN (?);
```

I'm going to have to use straight-up queries (unfortunately, no stored procedures).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query [`pg_constraint`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-constraint.html). For column names you should lookup [`pg_attribute`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-attribute.html). A foreign key may be based on multiple columns, so `conkey` and `confkey` of `pg_constraint` are arrays. You have to unnest the arrays to get a list of column names. Example:

```
select 
    conrelid::regclass table_name, 
    a1.attname column_name, 
    confrelid::regclass referenced_table, 
    a2.attname referenced_column,
    conname constraint_name
from (
    select conname, conrelid::regclass, confrelid::regclass, col, fcol
    from pg_constraint c, 
    lateral unnest(conkey) col, 
    lateral unnest(confkey) fcol
    where contype = 'f'   -- foreign keys constraints
    ) s
join pg_attribute a1 on a1.attrelid = conrelid and a1.attnum = col
join pg_attribute a2 on a2.attrelid = confrelid and a2.attnum = fcol;

 table_name | column_name | referenced_table | referenced_column |    constraint_name     
------------+-------------+------------------+-------------------+------------------------
 products   | image_id    | images           | id                | products_image_id_fkey
(1 row)
```

---

In Postgres 9.4 or later the function `unnest()` may have multiple arguments and the inner query may look like this:

```
...
    select conname, conrelid::regclass, confrelid::regclass, col, fcol
    from pg_constraint c, 
    lateral unnest(conkey, confkey) u(col, fcol)
    where contype = 'f'   -- foreign keys constraints
...
```